# Ajax request does not resolve in correct url

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, http, axios

I am trying to get data from this url:

```
axios.get('/join-us-donate')
```

It SHOULD be sent through **`web.php`**:

```
Route::get('/join-us-donate', [CMSController::class, 'joinUsDonate']);
```

and run this function from **`CMSController.php`**:

```
public function joinUsDonate()
{
    $data = DB::table('table')->first('order by id desc');
    return $data;
}
```

but it doesn't. Instead `axios.get` returns the whole `welcome.blade` of my laravel project, which is confusing since all other ajax requests of in the project work fine. But I can't get this one to work.

There are no similarly named urls in `web.php`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Dev-tools network panel:

[image]

**`web.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


// ##### AJAX REQUESTS FROM VUE FRONTEND TO NOVA CMS #####
// PAGELOADER
Route::get('/page-loader', [CMSController::class, 'nav']);

// NAVBAR
Route::get('/nav', [CMSController::class, 'nav']);

// HOME
Route::get('/home', [CMSController::class, 'home']);

// NEWS + NEWS OVERVIEW
Route::get('/blog-index', [CMSController::class, 'blog']);
Route::get('/blog', [CMSController::class, 'blogOverview']);

// VISION
Route::get('/vision', [CMSController::class, 'vision']);

// EVENTS + EVENTS OVERVIEW + EVENT CALENDAR IMAGE
Route::get('/event-index', [CMSController::class, 'events']);
Route::get('/event', [CMSController::class, 'eventCalendar']);
Route::get('/event-calendar-image', [CMSController::class, 'eventCalendarImage']);

// ARTWORK
Route::get('/artwork', [CMSController::class, 'artwork']);

// ABOUT
Route::get('/about', [CMSController::class, 'about']);

// DONATE
Route::get('/donate', [CMSController::class, 'donate']);
Route::get('/join-us-donate', [CMSController::class, 'joinUsDonate']);

// CONTACT
Route::get('/contact-info', [CMSController::class, 'contactImage']);

// PARTNERS
Route::get('/partners', [CMSController::class, 'partners']);

// FOOTER SLOGAN
Route::get('/slogan', [CMSController::class, 'footerSlogan']);

// LEGAL PAGES (terms of service, legal notice, privacy)
Route::get('/legal', [CMSController::class, 'legalPage']);

// SOCIAL MEDIA
Route::get('/social-media', [CMSController::class, 'socialMedia']);


// ##### CONTACT MAIL ROUTE #####
Route::post('/contact', [ContactController::class, 'submit']);

// ##### NEWSLETTER SIGN UP #####
Route::post('/newsletter', [NewsletterController::class, 'store']);
```

Response header:

[image]

Comment: What URL is requested in your browser dev-tools _Network_ panel?

Comment: Can you show us your web.php?

Comment: @Phil @Pareshmaheshwari I've added the information. Please see the `edit section`

Comment: Looks like the request to `join-us-donate` is being redirected. What does the `Location` response header look like for that request in your dev-tools?

Comment: Also, have you tried clearing your browser cache? It may have recorded an earlier 302 response for that URL.

Comment: @Phil cache reset does not help. I've added the `response header`  to edits but there is no `location` tab.

Comment: You have a redirect. is the /join-us-donate route protected by a middleware ?

Comment: @Wildfire sorry, how would I check that? I haven't edited `middleware` manually.